# Intersect One and Two-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, intersect

I have an array that has labels assigned to keys and an array that has those keys. I need to intersect those two arrays by single dimensional value and multidimensional key. Is there a single php function that allows this? I've read through the php array functions but couldnt really find something that fits.

```
$labels = array( 
    '7d' => __( 'Wöchentlich', 'aboprodukt' ),
    '14d' => __( 'Alle zwei Wochen', 'aboprodukt' ),
    '1m' => __( 'Monatlich', 'aboprodukt' ),
    '2m' => __( 'Alle zwei Monate', 'aboprodukt' ) );

$get_options = array( '7d','14d','1m');
```

this should result in:

```
$result = array(
    '7d' => __( 'Wöchentlich', 'aboprodukt' ),
    '14d' => __( 'Alle zwei Wochen', 'aboprodukt' ),
    '1m' => __( 'Monatlich', 'aboprodukt' ) );
```

(without the '2m' key->value-pair)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$result = array_filter($labels, 
    function($k) use($get_options) {
        return in_array($k, $get_options);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

but you could also do something like this:

```
array_intersect_key($labels, array_flip($get_options));
```

Comment: @Anselm none of the arrays are sorted, so i suppose that they are pretty close one to the other

Comment: but if I had to guess, since keys are unique (and php treats arrays as hashtable), probably the second one is faster, because `array_intersect_key` can check a key on the second array in O(n), at most O(logn), so it's n*logn AT MOST (but it's probably O(n)), but the first one must be n^2, so probably the second one is faster

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter` with third parameter [`ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`](http://php.net/manual/en/array.constants.php#constant.array-filter-use-key) to filter only keys.

```php
array_filter($labels, 
    fn($label)=>in_array($label, $get_options),
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```